# Upload signed URL never receive response / stuck

Tags: go, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url, signed-url

I generate upload signed URLs for a GCS Bucket using V4 method.

To generate my signed URL, I use the go storage package: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-go

Here is my code:

```golang
signedURL, err := storage.SignedURL(bucketFileStorage, fileID, &storage.SignedURLOptions{
    GoogleAccessID: serviceAccount.ClientEmail,
    PrivateKey:     []byte(serviceAccount.PrivateKey),
    Method:         "PUT",
    Expires:        time.Now().Add(30 * time.Minute),
    Scheme:         storage.SigningSchemeV4,
})
```

I upload my file using cURL, like this:

```sh
curl -X PUT {{MyUploadURL}} --upload-file /path/to/my/file.xxx
```

It work perfectly with some files (PNG, JPEG, JSON, etc...) but with some random files, my curl never receive response and wait indefinitely.
I try with insomnia, in case of my cURL client is in cause but I have the same pattern.

**Any idea why? I guess the file is the cause, but I don't know why, and how to check this.**

- [Here is a working file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znQs9.jpg)
- [Here is a not working file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgI4u.jpg)

Comment: Given the fact that you do not have a response, we can't know if this is an issue with GCS or something in your network. Does this happen with other upload methods such as gsutil?

Comment: Great idea ! I've tried to upload my files using `gsutil cp` and it work perfectly...

Comment: That indicates to me that this is not an issue with GCS or your files then, but something may be getting in the way of your requests when you do them via cURL. Do you have any firewall or network settings?

Comment: No firewall, no network settings, no vpn, nothing special...  :/